# Dusk Test Fails When Chrome Headless Enabled

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-chrome-headless, laravel-dusk

I have an HTML element that is supposed to display only on the first page load. Javascript sets a cookie and the element is not displayed if the cookie is set (PHP checks the cookie and doesn't render the content if the cookie exists).

I am trying to make a laravel dusk test for this and the test works fine when I disable --headless but the element is still seen if --headless is enabled.

Here is the test:

```
$browser->visit('/')
    ->visit(new ThePage($param))
    ->assertSee('element text')
    ->visit(new ThePage($param))
    ->assertDontSee('element text');
```

**This seems to be because javascript in headless chrome is not setting the cookie.**

Checking 
->assertPlainCookieValue('hide_element', 'hide');
supports this.

Is there a way around this?

(edit) Here is the HTML element I'm trying to hide:

```
<div id="cookiePolicy" class="cookie-policy">
    <p>element text</p>
</div>
```

Screenshots

Element shows:
[image]

Element Hides:
[image]

Here is the JS that sets the cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'hide_cookie_policy=hide;path=.domainname.com;expires= Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT';
```

Comment: JavaScript should work the same in headless mode. Maybe it's a timing issue, try replacing `assertDontSee` with `waitUntilMissing`.

Comment: You are some kinda genius! I think this is working... ... I had tried inserting pauses but those didn't work... thanks a TON. If you make that an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Oh man... I was wrong! I just double-checked the documentation. I didn't realize waitUnitllMissing was looking for a CSS selector. It's still not working unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Can you test the element absence with a selector? There is no built-in method to wait for text to disappear.

Comment: No problem! I tried that without any luck :(.

Comment: Can you post that part of your HTML?

Comment: Done! I had tried using waitUntilMissing('.cookie-policy') without any luck.

Comment: But if you use `->pause(5000)` and take a screenshot, the element isn't visible?

Comment: Correct. When headless mode is disabled everything works perfectly... and looks as we'd expect.

Comment: And in headless mode (screenshots are also possible)?

Comment: Sure thing, I posted screenshots. The element shows as it should... the page reloads... and then it's hidden as it should be.

Comment: What happens when you use `waitUntilMissing('.cookie-policy')`? Do you get a timeout exception?

Comment: Correct, I get "Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeOutException: Waited 5 seconds for removal of selector [.cookie-policy]."

Comment: There is definitely no other `.cookie-policy` element on your page?

Comment: Just looked to make sure; that's correct

Comment: When you get the timeout exception, Dusk automatically creates a screenshot. Is the element visible on it?

Comment: I forgot about the screenshots on fail! I just checked. The element is still showing up the second time around in the screenshot.

Comment: By the way, surrounding my element in the blade file is this:
@if($hideCookiePolicy === false)
(element)
@endif

Comment: So the cookie isn't being set... I'm just not sure why. I've done a check to confirm this.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code that sets the cookie?

Comment: Question updated with JS. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177204/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-user2305673).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by a self-signed SSL certificate.

After adding `->setCapability('acceptInsecureCerts', true)` to `DuskTestCase::driver()`, the cookie works.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the same result in a slightly different manner, which some may find useful...

In project-name\tests\DuskTestCase.php, I modified the `addArguments` call from this...

```
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--headless'
]);
```

...to this...

```
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--headless',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors'
]);
```

Passing the `--ignore-certificate-errors` argument appears to achieve the same result as setting the `acceptInsecureCerts` capability to `true`, whilst retaining the existing capabilities.