# Laravel Dusk Tests Fail In GitHub CI, But Work Locally

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I have spent a long time trying to debug this, but every solution I tried didn't work.

I have a project ([here](https://github.com/ebebbington/copytube/blob/master/.github/workflows/master.yml#L56)) containerised using docker, and the project itself uses Laravel, Nginx and Dusk.

If i try build the environment and run the dusk tests, they pass. Yet when i push this up to GH, the tests fail. I have `dump()`ed inside the CI, and it seems to show an empty page (`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`).

I feel like i've searched the whole internet at this point.

How i run my tests:

```
$ cd src/copytube
$ npm ci
$ npm run dev
$ composer install
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec copytube_phpfpm php artisan dusk
```

Don't suppose anyone has any idea as to why/how tests would fail **only in the CI**? The only difference between local and the CI i can think of is, I use a Mac, whereas the CI uses an ubuntu runner. But even then, because everything is containerised, it shouldn't be a problem

**EDIT**

On every single test, it errors, saying `Element oes not exist`, which makes sense becausee the page is just an empty body, the tests can be found [here](https://github.com/ebebbington/copytube/tree/master/src/copytube/tests/Browser)

**EDIT 2**

The CI failing can be seen [here](https://github.com/ebebbington/copytube/runs/1740767991?check_suite_focus=true) (old action)

I've disabled the dusk tests from running inside the workflow

**EDIT 3**

D:
I'll re-enable the tests so it can be easier to see

**EDIT 4**

Here's a PR where I enabled the dusk tests in the CI so you can see the errors: https://github.com/ebebbington/copytube/pull/161

Comment: what it's  the error?

Comment: I could probably expand upon that whoops, i'll update the description, but I after logging in, and trying to click or get any elements, it shows `element does not exist` which makes sense as the page is just an empty html body

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of problem when I was setting in the .env file as APP_URL a URL that starts with **https://**

So I guess that the problem is related to the .env file that you using on Github CI to run the tests.

Here is my answer related to that.
[Laravel Dusk returns empty html document when dumping browser, assertions therefore fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669269/laravel-dusk-returns-empty-html-document-when-dumping-browser-assertions-theref/71232545#71232545)